# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES (Angular 14/Angular Universal/Firebase Hosting&Cloud Functions)

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular14

I am trying to implement Server Side Rendering using Angular 14 with Angular Universal and Firebase Cloud Functions. I used this tutorial:

> https://gist.github.com/debojyoti/d75a517f77d8e5881d87553f1e493614

as a guide. I followed all the necessary steps. When trying:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting, functions
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load function definition from source: 
Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES 
Module D:\chadoulis.gr\chadoulis\functions\node_modules\@angular\platform- server\fesm2015\platform-server.mjs not 
supported. Instead change the require of D:\chadoulis.gr\chadoulis\functions\node_modules\@angular\platform-server\fesm2015\platform server.mjs 
to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

It seems that the main problem has to do with the `index.js` file produced inside the `functions` folder. This file goes like this:

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ps = require('@angular/platform-server');
const index = require('fs')
  .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/browser/index.html'), 'utf8')
  .toString();

let app = express();

app.get('**', function(req, res) {
  ps.renderModule(AppServerModule, {
    url: req.path,
    document: index
  }).then(html => res.status(200).send(html));
});

exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Any ideas?